# gradle - call custom task before gradle repositories resolution takes place

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using `gradle-7.2` I want to call custom task to derive svn branch and then use the same in repository URLs, couldn't find a way to do that.

this is my custom task in `build.gradle`:

```
task svninfo {
    println "***svninfo***"
    doLast {
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'svn'
                args = ['info']
                standardOutput = os
            }
            def outputAsString = os.toString()
            println "outputAsString #: $outputAsString"
            def matchSvnBranch = outputAsString =~ /URL:.*\/branches\/(.*)\/deployready\/.*/
            //def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/
            def branchName=${matchSvnBranch[0][1]}
            println "svn branch #: ${matchSvnBranch[0][1]}"
            println "svn.branch #: ${branchName}"
            ext.branch = branchName
            
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    //svninfo() --- not working, getting error
    maven {
            url "myurl-$branch"
            
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
}
```

**Update:**
As per the comment, i changed to `doFirst {}`, but still getting the error. Im not able to call `svninfo` task inside `repositories` closure. getting below error:

```
Could not find method svninfo() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
```

Please guide me on how to call svninfo() task before repositories evolution, so that i can use the variable `branch` in maven Url..

Comment: task def: do not use `doLast {}` - since you want this to be done at initialisation.

Comment: i changed it to `doFirst {}` but still getting the error. basically im not able to call `svninfo()` task inside `repositories()` closure, not sure how to do that..

Comment: just remove the doLast{} and doFirst{}

Comment: nope.. same error.. i believe its not problem with `svninfo` task def but with the way i'm calling.. something im missing .. unable to figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after couple of trial and errors, finally this worked:

```
def svninfo() {
    println "***svninfo***"
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'svn'
                args = ['info']
                standardOutput = os
            }
            def outputAsString = os.toString()
            println "outputAsString #: $outputAsString"
            def matchSvnBranch = outputAsString =~ /URL:.*\/branches\/(.*)\/deployready\/.*/
            def branchName=matchSvnBranch[0][1]
            println "svn branch #: ${matchSvnBranch[0][1]}"
            println "svn.branch #: ${branchName}"
            ext.branch = branchName
            
        }
}

svninfo()

repositories {
                maven {
                    url "myurl-$branch"
                    
                    allowInsecureProtocol = true
                }
            }
```

Not sure why defining as task was not working. Now i'm trying to move this logic to init script as this is going to be common logic for modules.